# Why is net.tcp IIS port configured under "Binding Information" instead of under "Port"

Tags: .net, wcf, iis, port, net.tcp

In IIS7 when you configure an http binding for your WCF services you set the port in the port column and the ip in the ip address column; but when you configure a net.tcp binding you have to cram it all in the "Binding Information" column like 808:*.  Why the inconsistency?  Somebody asked me why this was so, and I could not answer.